Is it OK to ask an unanswered question again, but written better?
I am new to this forum, so still feeling out the rules. I have asked a question and I fear I have added too much detail, where the actual question has got lost (this was pointed out to me in the comments).
I would like to ask the question again, but I don't want to remove all the detail of the previous question, because it could still be useful to someone. But I'm not sure if it's allowed to ask basically the same question again.
Original question
Challenge / Response to Prevent Replay Attack
Now that I've thought about it I think I can reduce this to a much more simple question (as indicated by my comment in this post). Is it better to edit the original and delete the detail or start a new one that gets straight to the point?

In your current case, there isn’t really a need to post another question just to enhance it. Since no one answered yet, no answers would get voided when you edit your current question. So, simply go ahead and modify it as you like and hit the save button.
In case of doubt: there’s an edit link at the bottom your question which enables you to modify the question (or simply click here – which is the same link, for your convenience).
